# Is there a way to speed up the load time of an HTML page that contains PHP?

Tags: php, html, json

Looking for any insights as to how to potentially speed up the page load time of the following:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<title>Tournament Details</title>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
</head>
<body>
<div class="content">
  <<h2><center><font face="libel" size="8px" color="#FF7A59">Past Tournaments</font></center></h2>
  <p>
  <table> 
<thead>
    <tr>
     <th>Date</th>
     <th>Game</th>
     <th>Type</th>
     <th>Link</th>
     <!--<th>Short URL</th>-->
     <th>Winner</th>
     <th># of Players</th>
    </tr>
</thead>
  <?php 
$apikey = 'MYAPIKEY';
$jsonData = json_decode(stream_get_contents(fopen("https://api.challonge.com/v1/tournaments.json?state=all&api_key=$apikey", "r")),TRUE);
$finalJsonArr = array_column($jsonData,'tournament');
rsort($finalJsonArr);
?>
<tbody>
    <tr>
        <?php foreach($finalJsonArr as $arr){ ?>
        <td><?php echo substr($arr['started_at'],0,10); ?></td>
        <td><?php echo strtoupper($arr['game_name']); ?></td>
        <td><?php echo strtoupper($arr['tournament_type']); ?></td>
        <td> <a href="<?php echo $arr['full_challonge_url']."/standings"; ?>"</a>CLICK TO VIEW RESULTS</td>
        <!--<td><?php echo $arr['url']; ?></td>-->
        <td><?php
$matches =  json_decode(stream_get_contents(fopen("https://api.challonge.com/v1/tournaments/".$arr['url']."/matches.json?state=all&api_key=$apikey", "r")),TRUE);
$participant =  json_decode(stream_get_contents(fopen( "https://api.challonge.com/v1/tournaments/".$arr['url']."/participants.json?state=all&api_key=$apikey", "r")),TRUE);
// Extract subarrays
$participants = array_column($participant, "participant");
// index by id
$participants = array_column($participants, null, "id");
$numItems=count($matches);
$i = 0;
foreach ( $matches as $match )  {
    // Extract player ID's
    $id1 = $match['match']['player1_id'];
    $id2 = $match['match']['player2_id'];
    $id3 = $match['match']['winner_id'];
if(++$i===$numItems) {
    echo $participants[$id3]["name"];
}
    }
?></td>
        <td><?php echo $arr['participants_count']; ?></td>
            </tr>
        <?php } ?>
</tbody>
</table>
</p>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

I'm positive it's the 5th Column containing the name of the winner that is bogging the page down, however I'm not sure how to do this any differently in order to improve load speed.

Comment: You mean if you could fetch the two remote resources in parallel it could speed it up already?

Comment: To answer the question in the title, PHP can never make HTML faster. At best it will be nearly identical in speed, but most likely it will slow it down, even just by microseconds. HTML is static, PHP is about doing “work” and work takes time. Your real question is “how to make this code faster”. Caching is a good start. Do those API calls need to be called on every page refresh? Those calls also have a DNS lookup in them which your server might not be doing smartly. Or, just use AJAX/XHR on the client side, pop a “loading” message, and it will feel faster for most people